# Time user is typing is zero even though it should be more in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, wpm

Im trying to calculate the time from when the user starts typing to when they stop. I put two variables start and end and subtracted them from each other. But it always returns zero. Can you give an easy way to calculate wpm if possible also? I want to in the end calculate the words per minute when the user types 10 words correctly. So I need the time from when they started to when they completed the prompt.

Thanks!

Javascript:

```
var input = document.getElementById("boch");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("bocho").click();
  }
});


var element = document.querySelector("#boch");

element.onkeyup = function () {
  var value = element.value;

   if (value.includes("m")) {
     var start = Date.now();
  } 

  if (value.includes("man")) {
    document.getElementById('word-1').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-1').style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

  if (value.includes("man become")) {
    document.getElementById('word-2').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-2').style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as")) {
    document.getElementById('word-3').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-3').style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as and")) {
    document.getElementById('word-4').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-4').style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as and through")) {
    document.getElementById('word-5').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-5').style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as and through find")) {
    document.getElementById('word-6').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-6').style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as and through find would")) {
    document.getElementById('word-7').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-7').style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as and through find would here")) {
    document.getElementById('word-8').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-8').style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as and through find would here and")) {
    document.getElementById('word-9').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-9').style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as and through find would here and before")) {
    document.getElementById('word-10').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-10').style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

   if (value.includes("man become as and through find would here and before")) {
     var end = Date.now();
 
  }
  let millis = end-start;

  console.log(millis)

  
}
```

HTML:

````
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<h1>
   <span id="word-1">man</span> <span id="word-2">become</span> <span id="word-3">as</span>
   <span id="word-4">and</span> <span id="word-5">through</span> <span id="word-6">find</span> <span id="word-7">would</span> <span id="word-8">here</span> <span id="word-9">and</span> <span id="word-10">before</span>
</h1>

<input type="text" id="boch" autocomplete="off">

        </div>
        <div id="typing-area">

      <button id="bocho" onclick="document.getElementById('boch').value = ''">Enter</button>

</html>




<script src="main.js"></script>```
````

Comment: Did you mean `==` instead of `includes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `value.includes("m")` is true everytime, so the timer restarts every time the function is fired. Instead, use `value === "m"`:

```
if (value === "m") {
  start = Date.now();
}
```

You need to declare `var end` and `var start` outside of the `if` statement and set it inside:

```
var start;
if (value === "m") {
  start = Date.now();
}
// other code...
var end;
if (value.includes("man become as and through find would here and before")) {
  end = Date.now();
}
let millis = end-start;
```

Also, I recommend putting a space between `end` and `start`. `end-start` could be a variable name.

Comment: It just gives zero.

Comment: You need to do the same for `start`. I'll edit

Comment: It still gives NaN and then 0.

Comment: @IrfanS instead of `value.includes("m")`, it should be `value === "m"`. I'll edit again

Comment: Sorry for bugging you, but it is now only giving NaN as an answer when i do console.log(millis)

Comment: @IrfanS could you share a codepen or a jsfiddle?

Comment: here is the link: https://codepen.io/IrfanVideo/pen/MWjdxOj

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227733/discussion-between-rojo-and-irfan-s).